# How to read contents of file using file path in react?

Tags: reactjs, csv, file

I have a file, `train_labels.csv`, that I'd like to read in as a string to pass onto a CSV reader.

I've tried doing:

```
const csv = new File("../data/train_labels.csv");
```

But it requires 2 arguments, the first argument being [bits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) which I'm not sure what it's referring to.

I've also tried using fetch:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("../data/train_labels.csv")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.text();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  });
```

But the console logs an html file instead.

Very lost here on something that is suppose to be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **any-text** package, for more documentation visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-text)

```
var reader = require('any-text');
    
reader.getText(`path-to-file`)
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **react-file-reader** package. For doc visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-reader).

For example, you can refer:

```
<ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes={'.csv'}>
    <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
</ReactFileReader>
```

and this.handleFiles can be written as:

```
handleFiles = files => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // Use reader.result
        console.log(reader.result)
    }
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to read in contents of a file using a file path though

Comment: just answered another one.